# ERROR: failed building wheel when installing spectral-cube (astropy)

Tags: python, pip, conda, python-wheel, astropy

I'm trying to install the package *spectral-cube* from the *astropy project* using pip (22.0.4). I get a long error which ends with this:

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for casa-formats-io.
> Failed to build casa-formats-io.
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for casa-formats-io, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Even after downloading casa-formats-io from their github I still get this error.
I've also tried installing this using conda, but the error is the same.
I'm using MacOS 12.3. But I had the problem with older versions.
I'm kind of confused as to what I can do.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my own problem. The error appeared because the package I was trying to download wasn't available/compatible with the newest python version (3.10). So, I simply uninstalled Python and downloaded an older version (3.8).

Thanks anyways :)